# React/Forms: How to wait for updated data by useEffect when the user submits data and submitting triggers the useEffect (which takes time)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a form in which, whenever the user enters data, other fields (might) be affected.
Therefore I extended the component which encapsulates the react-hook-form-fields in a way that it calls another function (`updateFormValues`) in its `onBlur`.
`updateFormValues` sends the current form data to the server and after having received the response, it updates the data.
Since setting state is `async`, I am using `useEffect` with the dependency array on `data` to wait until this is done. Whenever `useEffect` is called because of data, it resets the formValues with the [reset](https://react-hook-form.com/api#reset) method provided by react-hook-forms.

To avoid the user re-enterting values while the form is still being refreshed, I am setting an `isLoading` state in the function called by `onBlur` and clear `isLoading` after the `reset` is done. `isLoading` disables all form fields, which is acceptable.
This all works as intended.

But now here is the catch:
When the user types something in a field but does not leave it (so `onBlur` hasn't triggered yet), he can press the submit button.
Now, `onBlur` is triggered, but the form values have not been updated yet. As mentioned earlier, updating the form values with `reset` happens in `useEffect`, which is not called yet.
This leads to sending the server the old data: `api.post(formMethods.getValues())` still has the non-updated version.
How can I achieve to wait for the `useEffect` to finish in my button's `handleSubmit`?
The only way so far is to use `setTimeout(handleSubmit, 500). But this is very unsatisfying, since I cannot know for how long to wait. The more I wait, the worse the user experience. The less I wait, higher the chances of wrong data being sent.

Since I am incredible bad at codesandboxes (I will learn this on the next spare time,  it annoys me more than you), I hope this flow of actions is satisfying to support the written text:

1. User enters data
2. User presses Submit, this triggers `onBlur`
3. `onBlur` calls `updateFormValues`
4. the `formMethods.reset(parsedData)` is not done yet when `formMethods.getValues()` is called inside `handleSubmit`

The relevant methods:

```
  useEffect(() => {  
    const parsedData = doStuff(data);  
    formMethods.reset(parsedData);
    setLoading(false);
  }, [data]);

  const updateFormValues = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const result = await api.post('API_ENDPOINT',data) ;
    setData(result.data);
  };

 const handleDialogSubmit = async () => {    
    const isValid = await formMethods.trigger(); 
    if (isValid) {
      const allChanges = formMethods.getValues();               
      const result = await api.post('API_ENDPOINT', allChanges);     
      closeDialog();
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is ever stumbling upon this, here is my fix:

The `loading` state has been moved from the child component to its parent and is passed to it.
`handleDialogSubmit` has been renamed to `submitDialog` and this is the addtional logic to guarantee data only being submitted after the transformation has passed:

```
  const handleDialogSubmit = () => {
    setReadyToSubmit(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (readyToSubmit && !loading) {
      submitDialog();
    }
  }, [loading, readyToSubmit]);
```

I am not happy with this approach and think the overall way should be changed.
So, I won't mark this is accepted answer, in case someone has a better way.